# How to have two records for example.com both for MX and as CNAME for www.example.com

Tags: heroku, dns

I have a `CNAME` record for `www.example.com` with value of `www.example.com.herokudns.com`, and also for `example.com` with the value of `example.com.herokudns.com`.

The problem is that I do not know how to make `MX` records for a mail server on my domain provider server without losing the above functionality.

If I try to create `MX` records, the domain provider server complains that `CNAM`E exists for `example.com` and I must remove it. If I remove it and create records for `MX` as instructed by mail server provider, the mail starts working but browsing to `example.com` is not possible. Only `www.example.com` continues to work.

How I could solve this? I tried to google and read about CNAME similar questions here, but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a direct incompatibility with DNS based PaaS like Heroku which doesn't have a single static IP endpoint, and the nature of DNS.  You do have options, but you need to assess how each one compliments or counters the very reason you chose an integrated platform like Heroku in the first place.  Fortunately, there does look like there's some simple and effective solutions, depending on your exact configuration and providers:

#### The long and short of it is:

1. It's not standard to CNAME the apex '`@`'

   - See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/430971/411817), [here](https://serverfault.com/a/754347/411817), and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/91718/411817) for more details.
2. Heroku explain that you need to **use a DNS provider that supports CNAME functionality at the apex, or use sub-domains exclusively**

   - See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain
3. There's a good write-up on this specific topic here:

   - [Heroku and Root (aka “apex” or “naked”) Domains](http://smallchou.com/post/41388058201/heroku-and-root-aka-apex-or-naked-domains)

At face value, the [PointDNS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pointdns) addon looks dead simple:

```
heroku domains:add example-domain.com
```

[image]

**NOTE**: I've never tried PointDNS and have no opinion of them at all.  The suggestion is merely a copy/paste from a heroku article based on simplicity.

Comment: Thanks, I learned from the link you kindly gave that if CNAME is used over my root of the domain, everything gets redirect. Please tell me, is such a thing doable on a general domain provider control panel, to have two root domain but have them separated by type, so mail goes to mx redirection and http request to CNAME one? Any way? (I don't think I need to change heroku, there I already have 2 dns records for root and www)

Comment: @AdrianDain when heroku say *"you need to use a DNS provider that supports CNAME functionality at the apex"*, - I believe this is not just about *allowing* you to CNAME the root, but doing so with fully supported functionality to then add other records such as MX records to the apex.   What providers are you using ?  Your site is obviously heroku, but who is your mail provider and who hosts your DNS records ?

Comment: I'm on active-domain.com, for email I switched to Zoho, but after consulting with you and checking available options, I switched to AWS EC2 because I didn't have time and I must have had the web site working in a day. With a free tire account now I have my A record pointing to ip of EC2 and mx to Zoho, all working fine. I'm convinced to welcome the pain of setting up my own PAAS using Docker-Ansible-Kubernetes over DO, to have a (hopefully) lasting freedom! Thank you very much for your help!